# how to solve could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [patient_id]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am creating Rest web services , two entity patient and address, in post i want pass address as object along with patient attribute, but I am getting above error

PatientController.java

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Add a patient")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/patients", method= RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> createPatient(@Valid @RequestBody Patient patient, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            errors = new HashMap<>();
            for(FieldError error:bindingResult.getFieldErrors()) {
                errors.put(error.getField(), error.getDefaultMessage());
            }
            return new ResponseEntity<>(errors, HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
        }
        Address address = new Address();
        patient.getAddress().add(address);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(patientRepository.save(patient), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

patient.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "patients")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"}) 
public class Patient implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "patient_id", updatable = false)
    private UUID id;
    private String name;
    private String age;
    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date dob;
    private String occupation;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Gender gender= Gender.MALE;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "patient", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Address> address = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "patient", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Contact> contact;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "patient", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<ReferenceBy> references;

    public Patient() {}
    }
```

Comment: You have 2 `patient` having the same `id`

Answer (score 4):

`org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException` suggests that you are trying to insert a record which does not satisfy the constraint you have made. Please make sure you have a unique record for id and other fields which you have defined as unique